# How to re-replicate ignored tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, database-replication

I'm currently thinking about the following problem:

A customer has set up a simple master/slave replication between two mariaDB systems. For unknown reasons they have set the flag "Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table" to skip "logdb.%". Obviously, they decided to skip the skipping of that database and want the logdb to be included in the replication again.

I'm curious now, is it possible to somehow remove that flag and have the database in question be replicated as the rest or is there no way to circumvent the "stop slave, dump master, import dump, recreate replication based on current logpos, start slave" procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume that the master still has all relevant binlogs that once contained updates to the logdb.% tables. That is, even if you could re-apply those updates, do you have enough history to account for all changes to the tables?

Another risk is if you use statement-based replication, if there were ever statements that referenced both a table in logdb.% and a table in another database, the replication filter has skipped that statement. So for example:

```
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable SELECT * FROM logdb.othertable;
```

Therefore even the tables that are *not* in logdb.% might be compromised. The point is you don't know for sure.

The bottom line is that you should definitely reinitialize the replica now by taking a current backup of the master, and avoid using replication filters in the future.

If you use InnoDB tables, you might consider using Percona XtraBackup to make the process easier. See https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/howtos/setting_up_replication.html